# wpf textbox custom control type error

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

i wrote custom control base on TextBox which has also Minimum and Maximum inputs as follows:

```
    public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {
        static NumericTextBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NumericTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NumericTextBox)));
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(int), typeof(NumericTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

        public int Minimum
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(int), typeof(NumericTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(100));

        public int Maximum
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
        }


        public new static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(int), typeof(NumericTextBox),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                            default(int),
                                            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                            null,
                                            CoerceCurrentValue),
                                            IsValid);

        public new int Text
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }


        private static object CoerceCurrentValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            var numericTextBox = (NumericTextBox)d;
            var intValue = (int)baseValue;
            if (intValue < numericTextBox.Minimum) intValue = numericTextBox.Minimum;
            if (intValue > numericTextBox.Maximum) intValue = numericTextBox.Maximum;

            if ((int)baseValue != intValue)
                numericTextBox.Text = intValue;

            return intValue;
        }

        private static bool IsValid(object value)
        {

            if (value == null)
                return false;

            int intValue;
            var result = Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out intValue);

            return result;


        }
}
```

and in my xaml i call it:

```
<controls:NumericTextBox
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="5"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="100"
    />
```

it is bind to Test property in my view model (as int).
everything works good until i type a character and i get binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '1a'
>   (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=Text;
>   DataItem='NumericTextBox' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.    at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str,
>   NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info,
>   Boolean parseDecimal)    at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s,
>   NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)    at
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
>   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType,
>   IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type
>   type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter
>   converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter,
>   CultureInfo culture)'

it may be because the original Text property in TextBox is string... but i'm not sure.
please assist on that.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this in the wrong way. You are not restricting the input of the `TextBox` to only numerical numbers. The Framework is trying to convert a `string` into an `int` to fit into your `new int Text` property, but as the error says: *Input string was not in a correct format.*, eg. not an `int`. Try adding this into the constructor instead:

```
PreviewTextInput += new TextCompositionEventHandler((s, e) => e.Handled = 
    !e.Text.All(c => Char.IsNumber(c) && c != ' '));
PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler((s, e) => e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space);
```

They simply work by setting `e.Handled` to `true` if non numerical values are input and this has the effect of ignoring the input on those occasions.

Also, you don't need to implement your own `Text` property... that is just confusing matters. Just use the original one and parse the value into an `int` wherever you need to, resting assured that it *will* be a number. I think that these two handlers *should* ensure that. Let me know if you have any problems.

Another idea is to simply create an `AttachedProperty` using these handlers and then you can apply it to any `TextBox` control. Of course, you'd then need to implement your `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties as `AttachedProperties` too, but then you could do something like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Test} Attached:TextBoxProperties.IsNumeric="True" 
    Attached:TextBoxProperties.Minimum="0" Attached:TextBoxProperties.Maximum="100" />
```

You can find out more from the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) page on MSDN.

UPDATE >>>

If you don't want the user to be able to delete the last character from the `TextBox`, then we can just change one of the handlers to disallow it:

```
PreviewKeyDown += PreviewKeyDown;
...
private void PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space || 
    (textBox.Text.Length == 1 && (e.Key == Key.Delete || e.Key == Key.Back));
}
```

Comment: your solution not rely on dependency property binding characteristics,
but on PreviewKeyDown event.
i prefer to utilize the DP validation and coerce features instead.

this way i can have a red border around the textbox for incorrect value for example.

Comment: So you'd prefer to let the user enter incorrect values and alert them to that fact rather than to simply not allow them to enter incorrect values? Interesting. To do that, I'd prefer to use either the [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) or [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx) interfaces to provide full user feedback. However, the choice is of course yours.

Comment: it's a matter of UI design... how the user should know for example that only numeric is allowed.
IDataErrorInfo is also option to display generic message like "only numbers are allowed" - but again it should be implemented on the custom control and not on the view model.
your solution is good tho... i may stick with it.
but it has some limitation because u check every key input... so how can u check the range that way ? you always type behind the user input

Comment: Well named labels can give the user all the knowledge they need; 'Number of ...', 'Dealer price', 'Start year', etc. The handlers are an addition to whatever properties that you want to have. They just stop the user from entering non numerical characters, but you can still coerce the value to be between your `Minimum` and `Maximum` values in just the same way as you are now. The only real difference is that you won't get that `FormatException` anymore.

Comment: FormatException is raised when user delete all content in the textbox